# How to enter a hard-coded value to the database?

Tags: grails

I have a few fields in my User.groovy model class

```
fName
lName
userName
pwd
yourTel
```

The user will be entering the first 4 fields shown above. The 5th field `yourTel` will be hardcoded.

```
def create() {
   [userInstance: new User(params)]
}
```

How can I do it ?

This is what I already tried:

```
def create() {
    userInstance.yourTel = "2323232"
    params = userInstance.yourTe
    [userInstance: new User(params)] 
}
```

SAVE

```
def save() {
        def userInstance = new User(params)
        if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [userInstance: userInstance])

            return
        }else  {
            def userRole = Role.findOrSaveWhere(authority:'ROLE_USER')
            if(!userInstance.authorities.contains(userRole)){
                UserRole.create(userInstance, userRole, true)
            }
            redirect(controller:"login", action : "auth")
        }
    }
```

MODEL

```
static constraints = {
...
        yourTel blank:true , nullable: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach works too with a bit of tweak:

```
def create() {
    def instance = new User(params)
    instance.yourTel="2323232"
    [userInstance: instance]

}
```

The `[userInstance: instance]` the left is the key that will be used by your models, the right hand side is what you are passing to it. Here you first create the `new User(params)` then bind it with params and then you can tweak it and pass it back to your model.

```
def save() {
        def userInstance = new User(params)
        // set the yourTel to some value
        userInstance.yourTel="2323232" 

        if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
```

Comment: I get this error `Property [yourTel] of class [class com.app.User] cannot be null`. How can i sort this ?

Comment: It means when it is saving the object, the value is null. That is probably coming from your save action, set this property to your default value inside your save action or even in your domain if it always having that value, without seeing your code cannot say for sure.

Comment: set your value after this line `def userInstance = new User(params)`

Answer (score 1):

`params` is a map, so put your data like

```
params.yourTel="2323232"
```

or

```
params.put("yourTel","2323232")
```

Now your code becomes:

```
def create() {
    params.yourTel="2323232"
    [userInstance: new User(params)]
}
```

Comment: I get this error `Property [yourTel] of class [class com.app.User] cannot be null`. How to sort this out ?